# Остановка всех потоков, при возникновении Exception (C#)

Tags: c#, многопоточность, исключения

Имеется метод, который создает некоторое количество потоков. Как обработать эксепшены дочерних потоков в этом методе и остановить все дочерние потоки при поимке ошибки? Условие - .Net 3.5, то есть все исключительно с чистыми потоками.

```
StreamReaderByBlocks sr = new StreamReaderByBlocks(sourceFileStream, 32*1024*10);
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();

for (int i = 0; i < threadsCount; i++)
{
      Thread th = new Thread(CompressProcess);
      th.IsBackground = true;
      threads.Add(th);
      th.Start(sr);
}  

Thread thWriter = new Thread(Writer.Write);
thWriter.Start(new Writer.WriterParameters() { Queue = queue, outputFile = resultFile });
```

Comment: Cancellation token?

Comment: @tym32167, разве Cancellation token был в .Net 3.5 ?

Comment: я без понятия, но если и нет, то написать его простейшую реализацтю вроде не долюно быть проблемой